# How to fetch and set data in listview adapter using background thread?

Tags: android

I have an app which contain listview which get the list of installed apps in device and set it into adaptor but problem is that it freezes app for a second when getting list of apps installed in device. What i want to get these list and set it into adapter using background thread.How do i do that

code:-

```
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final List<CWhiteListAppsModel> installedApps = getInstalledApps();
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    installedAppAdapter = new CWhiteListAppsAdapter(mContext, installedApps, CWhiteListAppsFragment.this);
                    appCount();
                    userInstalledApps.setAdapter(installedAppAdapter);
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try implement AsyncTask as  inner class
this will show ProgressDialoginstead of shwing your app hanged, hope it helps!

```
 private class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<yourclass>> {

        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // start loading animation maybe?
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(DictionarySscWords.this,
                    "APPname",
                    "Loading....");
        }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<yourclass> doInBackground(String... params) {
       //fetch from database here
        return temp;


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<yourclass> yourclass) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
         //update list view here
        list.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(yourclass));
    }
}
```